# Is there a direct way of appending text to a DOM element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

Is there a more direct way of writing the following in jQuery?

```js
var $b = $('b');
$b.text($b.text() + ', World!!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<b>Hello</b>
```

This seams like something jQuery would have existing functionality for, as [vanilla JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/oyp3xedz/1/) can do it by direct access to the property.

```
document.querySelector('b').innerText += ', World!!';
```

I looked into the [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method, however it appears that it isn't designed for appending text, [even though it works](http://jsfiddle.net/jv8ef17h/1/):

```
$('b').append(', World!!');
```

Also the Additional Notes section warns of XSS vulnerabilities when using `.append()`, as it can potentially execute code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As you have already pointed out, the cleanest way is by modifying the property directly.

To do that in jQuery you can get the DOM element reference from within the object:

```
var $b = $('b');
$b[0].innerText += ', World!!';
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vx97vkm/2/)

*Or,*

You could pass a function to `.text()`, which isn't any 'cleaner' but can be very helpful if you want to use the context:

```
var $b = $('b');
$b.text(function(_,v){
    return v += ', World!!';
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vx97vkm/1/)

*Or,*

If it *really* bugs you, introduce your own jQuery method:

```
jQuery.fn.appendText = function(a){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).text(function(_,v){
            return v += a;
        });
    });
};
```

For use like so:

```
$b.appendText(', World!!');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vx97vkm/3/)

---

*'This seams like something jQuery would have existing functionality for, as vanilla JavaScript can do it by direct access to the property.'*

Is probably exactly why jQuery doesn't implement its own method to do so. Why waste valuable bytes with a method that will carry out something that is so easily done with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: It does tend to really bug me. I would prefer http://jsfiddle.net/fwh463cn/1/, but the XXS protection of `.text()` is paramount. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @robbmj Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

use `text()`

```
$('b').text("Hello");
```

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters
>   with their HTML entity equivalents (such as < for <)

When you use `.text()` jQuery uses `createTextNode` internally, which escapes all special characters.